# Are questions about a specific mixer appropriate?

Tags: discussion

I have a specific question about how to use a specific mixer (Behringer X2442-USB) and how to set it up to get specific ins & outs I want.  Is this an appropriate forum for that?

If not, can you suggest an appropriate S.E. site for that sort of thing?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I posted [my question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4160/how-to-get-line-level-record-out-on-behringer-x2442-usb), even though it may be brand/model-of-mixer specific.  If you think it would be better served in a different SE, let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: That is a great question.  Very well written.  I think you will get some good answers.

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be a good question for the site.  Questions for a specific mixer are usually applicable to mixers in general unless they focus on a specific feature unique to that mixer.  Try to word it in such a way that the question is more about the configuration than the mixer.

Example:

Title - How do I do X

Question - How can I do X on a mixer? (I have a Behringer X2442-USB)